# How to implement an in-place map method (map!) in ruby on a binary-tree?

Tags: ruby, methods, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement an in-place method on an object and I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't change the value of self (SyntaxError)
```

When trying to do

```
self = map(&block)
```

on the following object

```
class Node
  include Enumerable

  # binary tree representation
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  def initialize(value=nil, left=nil, right=nil)
    @value, @left, @right = value, left, right
  end

  def map(&block)
    res = Array.new
    res << yield(value) if value
    res << left.map(&block) if left 
    res << right.map(&block) if right
    res.flatten
  end

  def map!(&block)
    self = self.map(&block)
  end

  def to_a
    map { |a| a }
  end
end
```

I've also tried to use some of Enumerable's destructive methods to no avail

```
map(&block).collect!
```

What is wrong with my approach and how would you implement a function like this?

**Update**

To clarify the idea is to implement map on a binary tree, which the map method above does successfully, my problem is translating that method into an in-place version.

```
irb(main):001:0> require './node.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> root = @root = Node.new(1, Node.new(2, Node.new(3), Node.new(4)),Node.new(5, Node.new(6), Node.new(7)))
=> #<Node:0x78803f58 @value=1, @left=#<Node:0x78abc090 @value=2, @left=#<Node:0x78abc0f0 @value=3, @left=nil, @right=nil>, @right=#<Node:0x78abc0c0 @value=4, @left=nil, @right=nil>>, @right=#<Node:0x78803f88 @value=5, @left=#<Node:0x78abc060 @value=6, @left=nil, @right=nil>, @right=#<Node:0x78abc030 @value=7, @left=nil, @right=nil>>>
irb(main):003:0> root.map { |a| a * 3 }
=> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
irb(main):004:0> root
=> #<Node:0x778fb828 @value=1, @left=#<Node:0x778fb9c0 @value=2, @left=#<Node:0x778fba68 @value=3, @left=nil, @right=nil>, @right=#<Node:0x778fb9f0 @value=4, @left=nil, @right=nil>>, @right=#<Node:0x778fb888 @value=5, @left=#<Node:0x778fb930 @value=6, @left=nil, @right=nil>, @right=#<Node:0x778fb8b8 @value=7, @left=nil, @right=nil>>>
irb(main):005:0> root.map! { |a| a * 3 }
=> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]]
irb(main):006:0> root
=> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

Comment: Your title does not match the question.

Comment: How so? I´m tying to implement an in-place version of a method and have given my approach so far. What do you perceive my question to be?

Comment: The title asks how to implement it, and the question body asks what is wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually implemented like this:

```
class Node

  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right

  def initialize_copy(source)
    super
    @value = @value.dup
    @left = @left.dup
    @right = @right.dup
  end

  def map(&block)
    dup.map!(&block)
  end

  def map!(&block)
    @value.map!(&block) if @value
    @left.map!(&block) if @left
    @right.map!(&block) if @right
    self
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this solution is that it doesn't implement a map method for the binary tree as I expect it i.e. if the `@value` is a fixnum there is no map method. The map method I've got above works as I expect it, my problem is that I'm not sure how to translate that method into an in-place version. I'll update the question to make my intent clearer.

Comment: This is actually correct, most of my problems where caused by me not understanding what the map function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a keyword, and it is not a variable. That is why you cannot do assignment to it.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def update!
    self.instance_variables.each do |i| 
      self.instance_variable_set(i, yield(self.instance_variable_get(i)))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) gives you a bunch of methods based on your domain specific `each` method. None of the methods are destructive.

Instead, I would define your own methods using Enumerable:

```
class Node

  # define each and include, or do it by hand to customize:

  Enumerable.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      # apply method to each instance variable
    end
  end

  %w( map reject etc.. ).each do |method|
    define_method("#{method}!") do |*args|
      results = send(method)
      # modify instance vars based on results
    end
  end

end
```